# What constitutes an underground corruption biome?

Tags: terraria-console

I want to build my own underground biome, in something similar to an arena. How deep do I have to go, and how big does it have to be? I'm planning on placing ebonstone blocks to start the spread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The depth the underground starts at depends on the size of your world. The easiest way to make sure you are in the underground is to have a [Depth Meter](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Depth_Meter) (or one of the accessories made from a Depth Meter) equipped. Its status display should list "Underground" as your location.

In general, you need at least 200 blocks from the specified biome for the game to treat that area as that biome type, but some biomes have different requirements. The [Terraria wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Biome#Biome_Existence_Requirements) has a complete list of what is necessary to create each biome.